# Spring Batch: multiple writers

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a XML input files (very large) which must be processed in the following way:

- read each item X from xml file
- for each item X change some fields (such updated X will be denoted as X')
- write all updated X' items to new file
- transform each item X' to some new object Y
- write each transformed Y object to some other new file

Because input/output files are big, I used StaxItemReader and StaxItemWriter to read/write files. In the mean time I have implemented ComposedItemProcessor which transforms X to X' and then X' to Y. The question is: how can I easily use StaxItemWriter to write both: X' and Y?

The easiest way is to process in two steps:

- read from file -> transform to X' -> save X' to file UPDATED_X.xml
- read file UPDATED_X.xml -> transform to Y -> save Y in file Y.xml

but I would like to avoid unnecessary parsing.. Is possible to fork job and write both X' and Y?

Answer (score 0):

> In the mean time I have implemented ComposedItemProcessor which transforms X to X' and then X' to Y. The question is: how can I easily use StaxItemWriter to write both: X' and Y?

In this case, the type of input items of your `ComposedItemProcessor` is X and the output is Y. Y is the type of items going to your item writer. Hence your item writer would not be able to write X' items.

According to your requirement, `write all updated X' items to new file` and `transform each item X' to some new object Y` are what makes your steps inter-dependent. So I guess you would need to proceed in two steps as you mentioned.